# Koa - issue internal request

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa

We are using Koa to create a REST service.

One thing I would like to do is call an internal API from a middleware using a custom request object and parse the response before giving it to a real client.

If this is a bit hard to grasp, consider this pseudo code:

```
var myMiddleware = function(ctx, next) {

   var fakeSubRequest = new Koa.Request('GET', '/some-internal-path');
   var fakeSubResponse = yield koa.internalRequest(fakeSubRequest);

   ctx.body = someTransformation(fakeSubResponse.body); 

}
```

This entirely fictional. My point is that I want to 'simulate' a request in my application by creating a new request and receiving an new response, which I can then use to construct my actual response.

I don't want to call my routes and/or middlewares directly. I want it to go through the router because it must work server-wide.

Is it possible to simulate an internal request without doing a real HTTP request on localhost?

Comment: I guess creating a request to localhost would be the best options. Because the middlewares' logic mostly depend on NodeJs HTTP req/res objects (this.req, this.res), which are not created by Koa but handed over to Koa by NodeJs. Even if you call your router, you still need to create and pass HTTP req/res objects to it.

Comment: @zeronone having to invoke the TCP network stack would be a major performance hit. Is it not possible to create the nodejs request and response objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few years later, I have an answer.

The best approach is to create a new Context object from scratch and try to 'Mock' Node.js IncomingMessage and ServerResponse objects.

This is not easy and a bit of a hack, but it's what Koa requires right now. I ended up starting [a new Koa-inspired framework](https://github.com/curveballjs/core) that does this better.